# printing the output of a derefrenced variable into a file

Tags: perl

I had a written a module, just to bifurcate a file into training and test sets.  The output  is fine, but it would be really easy for the students if the output of the two referenced variables, `@$test` and `@$training` were redirected to two different files. Here is the code:

```
use Cut;

my($training,$test)=Cut::cut_80_20('data.csv') ;
print"======TRAINING======\n"."@$training\n";
print"======TEST==========\n"." @$test\n";
```

Comment: Wait, do I have this right? Are you *teaching* Perl?

Answer (score 3):

print takes an optional filehandle before the data to output.  Open your files and print away:

```
open( my $training_fh, '>', 'training.csv' ) or die "Couldn't open training.csv: $!";
print $training_fh "======TRAINING======\n"."@$training\n"; 
open( my $test_fh, '>', 'test.csv' ) or die "Couldn't open test.csv: $!";
print $test_fh "======TEST==========\n"." @$test\n";
```

Comment: thanks,just figured it out,here is the code use Cut;

my($training,$test)=Cut::cut_80_20('data.csv') ;
my@tr=@$training;
my@te=@$test;
 foreach(@tr)
{
 open FH,">>trainingset" or die "boo";
 print FH $_;
}
close FH;
foreach(@te)
{
 open FG,">>testset" or die "boo";
 print FG $_;
}
close FG;

Comment: I'm glad that works, but there's no need to assign to new arrays or print line line at a time or reopen the files each time you write a line.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy:

```
open my $fh1, '>', "training.out" or die "failed to open training.out ($!)";
print $fh1 "======TRAINING======\n";
print $fh1 "@$training\n";
close $fh1;
open my $fh2, '>', "test.out" or die "failed to open test.out ($!)";
print $fh2 "======TEST==========\n";
print $fh2 "@$test\n";
close $fh2;
```

Note the absence of a comma after the file handle in the print statements.  You can add newlines and such like as necessary.